# How to put more info in django through model?

Tags: django, model, admin

The purchaser bought one product type (including serveral products) each time from a supplier. I don't known how to add the procurement records in django admin, which including the bought date, the supplier name, the product type, the products name and their quantities.

```
class ProductSupplier(models.Model):
    product_supplier = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="product supplier")

class ProductType(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="product type")
    product_suppliers = models.ManyToManyField(ProductSupplier, through='BuyProducts')    

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="product name")
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="product type")

class BuyProducts(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_supplier = models.ForeignKey(ProductSupplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_bought = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return "bought %s from %s on %s" % (self.product_type, self.product_supplier, self.date_bought)
```

I can add or edit the procurement records in django admin, which including the bought date, the supplier name and the product type. However, I cannot add or edit the products name and their quantities. Any suggestion is very welcome.

The sql tables like these:

BuyProductType:
    buy_product_type_id, product_type_id, supplier_id, date_bought

BuyProductQuantity:
    buy_product_quantity_id, buy_product_type_id, product_id, quantity

Comment: You add extra fields to the `BuyProducts` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. Can you help me modify the BuyProducts model? The products's type is fixed and the quantities are flexible. I do not know how to modify the BuyProduct model.

Comment: "I can add or edit the procurement records in django admin, which including the bought date, the supplier name and the product type. However, I cannot add or edit the products name and their quantities." -- do you mean you can't update from `BuyProductsAdmin`?

Comment: @JasperLankhorst I know how to use Django admin via writing model with ManyToManyField using the through argument. My problem is do not know how to add extra field in the through model which is related to another field and having extra info.

Comment: @heemayl If I wrote BuyProducts like the code in my question, I can only update the bought date, the supplier name and the product type in the Django admin. I want to update the products name and their quantities in one procurement record, too. But I do not konw how to modify the BuyProducts model. Once the user choose the product type in Django admin, he can only choose product of this product type and input the quantity. So I can not simply add the product field and quantity field in the BuyProducts model.

Answer (score 0):

I have basically solved this problem via adding a relation model with ForeignKey to the through model.

```
class BuyProductQuantity(models.Model):
    buy_product = models.ForeignKey(BuyProducts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

And the admin.py like this:

```
class BuyProductsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BuyProducts
    extra = 2
class ProductTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BuyProductsInline]
    list_display = ('product_type',)
class BuyProductsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('buy_product', 'product_name', 'product_quantity')
admin.site.register(ProductType, ProductTypeAdmin)
admin.site.register(BuyProductQuantity, BuyProductsAdmin)
```

At the ProductType admin page, I can update the BuyProducts info. At the BuyProductQuantity admin page, I can select one buy_product and update product name and quantity.

However, there is still an issue. At the BuyProductQuantity admin page when I select one buy_product from the drop list, I want to filter the product drop list according to the selected product type.